# What's the difference between const T & and T & in template deduction

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

```
#for example:

#1:
template <typename T>
void func(T &) {}
int a;
const int b;
func(a);           // T ->  int
func(b);           // T ->  const int
func(5);           // wrong. 5 is a right value

#2:
template <typename T>
void func(const T &) {}
int a;
const int b;
func(a);     // T ->  int
func(b);     // T ->  int   
func(5);     // T ->  int

#3
template <typename T>
void func(T &&) {}
func(5);     // T ->  int
```

My question is:

why the 1'st code doesn't work,Why this is related to left/right value;

why `T` in the 3'rd is not `const int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all comes down to the properties of expressions. `5` is an expression. It has a type and a value category. The type of `5` is `int`, not `const int` but just plain `int`. And it's a prvalue (that's the value category).

So when deducing `T&` against a `5`, the type can only be deduced as `int`. Which means the synthesized function accepts a `int&`, which cannot bind to an rvalue.

When deducing `T const&`, the type `T` may still only be deduced as `int` under the appropriate provisions in template argument deduction. But now the synthesized function accepts a `int const&`, and that may bind to an rvalue just fine.

Comment: why T can not deduced as const int

Comment: @BAKEZQ - Because it's not given a `const int` to deduce from, it's given an `int`. `5` (as a literal) has the type `int`.

Comment: `void compare(T *, T *); compare("qw", "qwe")` How this works.The function has given a `const char *`.Then how to explain the deduciton.

Comment: @BAKEZQ - What's to explain? String literals are a different beast. They are **lvalues**, for one. And have type `char const[N]` for some `N`. So when they decay to pointers the `const` remains.

Answer (score 1):

> why the 1'st code doesn't work;Why this is related to left/right value;

For the 1st case, `T` will be deduced as `int`, then the parameter type is `int &`, which is an lvalue-reference to non-const. And `5` is an rvalue, which can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const and then invocation fails.

For the 2nd case, the parameter type of the function is `const int &`, i.e. an lvalue-reference to const, which could bind to rvalue like `5`.

> why `T` in the 3'rd is not `const int`

Template argument deduction won't *add* `const` if the argument is not of type `const`. `5` is of type `int` (and it's an rvalue), but its type is not `const int`.

On the ohter hand, we have [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) for dealing with lvalues/rvalues. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
void func(T &&) {}
int a;
const int b;
func(a);           // T ->  int&;       parameter type -> int&
func(b);           // T ->  const int&; parameter type -> const int&
func(5);           // Fine. T ->  int;  paramter type -> int&&
```

Comment: But this is a template. Why can not deduct to const int & in  1st case and T becomes to const int.